# Creating Qmenu from QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt4, pyside

I have a QAbstractItemModel (a tree) that gives me valid key=value pairings:

```
+ key1
    + val1
    + val2
+ key2
    + val3
    + val4
    + val5
```

I further have a QTableView showing the key=value pairs assigned to an object in my app. E.g.:

```
| Key  | value |
+------+-------+
| key1 | val1  |
```

The QTableView has a custom context menu to add new key=value pairs to the object. Is there (or has anyone build) something to generate a menu structure from an QAbstractItemModel?

Bonus points for:

1. displaying a checkmark before keys and values the object already has. I think this could use a proxy model that sets the checkmark role so the menu factory only has to use that.
2. ghosting unselectable items

Note: I'm looking for python code

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mrvn/53fcbd810ab3fdd796c8

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow. Please don't link to code on external sites: put the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: I don't think the code in the gist is relevant. The question is about building a Menu from a abstract tree model. That's the part that is just a comment in the gist.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It just eases the work of potentially helping users so they don't have to write everything from scratch to test it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow. Sorry to say this, but it sounds very much like you're begging for code (in fact, you practically say as much in the last line of your question). If you don't provide *any* relevant code, it strongly suggests you have made no effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: What's the model behind the QTableView?  Presumably not the same model. Can you justify using the QAbstractItemModel as the source for the QMenu?  THis is not particularly supported by Qt and is going to be cumbersome.  It would be easier to build the QMenu from all sorts of other native structures eg dictionary or list of lists.

Comment: The QTableView has a QAbstractTableModel. But that doesn't really matter. The menu could be a context menu of a QTreeView, a button or any other kind of widget. As for using QAbstractItemModel for the menu: Using the model/view concept seems like the natural idea instead of inventing my own data structure. A `QMenu menu; menu.setModel(model) ` would be ideal.